# Batch file to copy, concatenate, and remove tab

Tags: text, automation, batch-processing

I got tab delimited files produced by radio automation software. One file for one day with following content: date time artist title. I need this files intact, but also need following scenario: when first file gets produced needs to be duplicated , renamed and remove first two fields(date and time). Than all the proceeding files must be concatenated in this file with only artist and title.

Is this possible at all? 
 Tnx

Answer (score 0):

In Bash I'd just do it with awk

```
awk -F "\t" '{print$1"\t"$2}' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Basically what this does, is grab "\t" which stands for a tab, and it grabs data before the first tab ($1) then makes it replace the first tab with "\t", another tab. and then it grabs the data behind the second tab ($2).

Let's say these are the contents of your current file1:

date:time:artist:title

You want to make file2 print out artist  (tab) title

The awk code in your bash script would be:

```
awk -F ":" '{print$3"\t"$4}' file1.txt > file2.txt
```